# RegEx pattern not asserting true

Tags: java, regex, assert

I am trying to compare the below string to a regular expression pattern in my java project:

***2018-11-12 12:02:04.075***

I've passed the above string into an online regular expression generator to generate the following pattern:

***((?:2|1)\d{3}(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))***

Below is my ASSERT statement, but when I run this test I get an assertion error:

```
assertTrue(rs.getString(this.columnName).matches("((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]))"));
```

What changes do I need to make to get this test to pass? Is it a problem with my regex?

Comment: I don't know the defaults for Java's `matches` method but are you sure it isn't trying to match the whole string?

Comment: This seems a lot more complicated than just using a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).  For that matter, why not define your database column as a datetime or timestamp column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using one of the following regexes:

```
((?:2|1)\d{3}(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9].(?:[0-9][0-9][0-9])))
```

or

```
((?:2|1)\d{3}(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9]).(\d{3}))
```

or

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}).(\d{3})
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one worked for me. May I ask what the difference is between these 3 options. And is there a preferred one? I would think the shorter one would be preferrable?

Comment: first one will match date-time with different separators

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the miliseconds part. Try this:

```
((?:2|1)\\d{3}(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:-|\\/)(?:(?:0[1-9])|(?:[1-2][0-9])|(?:3[0-1]))(?:T|\\s)(?:(?:[0-1][0-9])|(?:2[0-3])):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])\\.\\d{3})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[12]\\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[12])-(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[01])\\s([01][0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\\.\\d{3}
```

Comment: This answer would be improved by explaining why the particular pattern meets the requirements. Also, by not checking the first digit, this will match `9999-46-98 76:62:99.000`, so I think it is too broad of a match.

Comment: @KevinO the question was to match a specific date-time format, which used "-" as separator, and did not specify year range, though I've limited it upon your suggestion

Comment: I think this is improved. While the specific text did not specify a year range, the OP's attempt was to try to limit the possible validity, so it seems appropriate to keep close to what the OP at least attempted.